# Full calendar, los eventos se pisan

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Hola una pregunta alguna manera para que no se pisen los eventos? [image: Los eventos se pisan]

mi codigo para mostrar los eventos es este:

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
  var user = $('#iduser').val();
  $.get('horario/' + user, function (data) {
    var events = [];
    $.each(data, function (index, subcatObj) {
      events.push({
        start: subcatObj.start_date,
        end: subcatObj.end_date,
        color: 'red',
        title: 'Cerrado',
        dow: [subcatObj.dow],
        id: subcatObj.idhorario_cancha
      });
    });
    callback(events);
  });
},
```

Comment: La respuesta corta es si, la respuesta larga es... Necesitamos ver el código que registra los eventos.

Comment: listo agregue mi codigo

Answer (score 1):

Es una propiedad del calendario en si, la propiedad [slotEventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/) te permite evitar que los eventos se pisen entre ellos peroesta implementación implica que algunos eventos sean reducidos al mostrarse.

Por defecto ésta propiedad está activada, es necesario ponerla en `false`para obtener la funcionalidad que deseas.

También cabe mencionar que esta propiedad solamente funciona en las vistas `agendaWeek` y `agendaDay`.

La implementación de esta propiedad se debe hacer en el llamado al calendario:

```
$('#calendario').fullCalendar({
  slotEventOverlap: false
});
```

Comment: y como lo aplico?

Answer (score -2):

listo lo pude solucionar, el codigo que usé fue el siguiente:

```
selectOverlap:false,
```

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad por su longitud y contenido. Deberías editarla para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué hace `selectOverlap`? ¿cómo solucionó tu problema?